# switching to dispatcher thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

This is the follow up to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703807/calling-method-indefinitely).

I have to update a ObservableCollection from a different Thread. I tried it with the following Code:

```
            Thread t = new Thread(  ()=>
         {
             while(true)
             {

                 if (ErrorDetection.ErrorDetectionIO.doErrorDetection() == 1)
                 {
                     dataLine = ErrorDetection.ErrorDetectionIO.getDataLine();

                     if (mainWindow != null)
                     {
                         ISynchronizeInvoke target = mainWindow; // mainWindow needs to be an WindowsForm?
                         target.Invoke(
                            (Action)(() =>
                             {
                                mainWindow.setNewDataLine(dataLine);
                             }
                             ), null);
                     }

                 }
             }

         }  );

         t.IsBackground = true;
         t.Start();
```

ErrorDetectionIO.doErrorDetection() is in a c++/cli .dll and calls native c Code.

setNewDataLine is on the mainWindow and adds a Line to the Observable Collection.

If its called from a different Thread it causes an exception:
"This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

The Problem is that ISynchronize Invoke does not seem to work with wpf? Threres an compiler error message that mainWindow can´t be converted to ISynchronizeInvoke.

if I use 
ISynchronizeInvoke target = mainWindow as ISynchronizeInvoke;
it can be compiled but target is null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke` instead of trying to cast to `ISynchronizeInvoke`.  [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) will provide the correct marshaling for WPF.

Note that .NET 4.5 adds the ability for WPF to handle this automatically by setting [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out some of the many [ThreadSafeObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37312/ThreadSafeObservableCollection) implementations. These will wrap up the problem of updating an ObservableCollection from a background thread quite nicely!